# executable file for firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

i want to create an executable file for firefox. i am not able to find solution for this. creating an exexcutable for firefox with a double click feature.

As now to install an extension we drag n drop the xpi file.

Comment: Do you mean that you want an executable that will start Firefox and install an extension? Or I didn't understand anything...

Comment: I want to create a executable file for the firefox extension. i dun wanna user to drag n drop it. i want to make it install in double click.

Comment: Users don't usually need to drag - they click a link on the web and it installs the extension. Do you have problems making it work or do you have some entirely different approach to distributing extensions?

Comment: i have made the firefox extension. but when i have to run it i have to drag n drop the xpi file on the firefox browser window. so i want a downable executable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it may be a language issue, but I can't quite work out your question. Are you saying that you want to be able to double-click an XPI file and have it automatically install in Firefox?

If so [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) says you can use command-line parameters to either "visit" an add-on file, or globally install it.

In Windows I would set up a file-type handler for .XPI files that executes one of these commands:

- `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -url "%1"` which opens the file, thereby installing it; or
- `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -install-global-extension "%1"` which explicitly installs the XPI globally on the machine.

The only way I know to add the handler involves manually editing the Windows registry, which is fraught with peril so I won't describe it unless there are no easier solutions forthcoming.

Note: your path to Firefox may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Just shift right click the file and choose open with. Select firefox and check always use this program and you are done.

Comment: sorry , but i want the exe file for the firefox extension.